# Performance compare (normal function call vs for_each+mem_fun vs lambda expression) in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, visual-c++-2010

Which is the best one (in performance) among these snippets?

1)

```
for(list<Enemy*>::iterator iter = enemies.begin(); iter != enemies.end(); iter ++)
   (*iter)->prepare(time_elapsed);
```

2)

```
for_each(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), [time_elapsed] (Enemy *e) {e->prepare(time_elapsed);});
```

3)

```
for_each(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), bind2nd(mem_fun1<void, Enemy, GLfloat>(&Enemy::prepare), time_elapsed));
```

Comment: You could easily measure this yourself in the time it takes someone to put together an answer.

Comment: i'd think 2 has the best chance. (1) has some inefficiencies (calling `end` multiple times and using post-increment).

Comment: Wrap each statement in a scope and place a `boost::progress_timer` at the start of the scope. That will tell you.

Comment: I mean, which one of these incur in less overhead? I don't want to measure the running time

Comment: @bubman: I think that is quite impossible to tell without actually measuring. Each compiler may be able to optimize those three (or not) differently.

Comment: If you don't want to measure the running time, then what metric *do* you want to use to talk about performance? Or do you just mean that *you* don't want to measure running time — you want *someone else* to measure it *for* you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas are the fastest solution. There are special optimizations involved with taking references to stack-based variables. In addition, in C++0x, they're FAR more flexible than any of that bind stuff, and the first loop also has the clarity disadvantage. Lambdas are the winrar in every way.

However, I'm seriously thinking micro-optimization, unless this is in a really, really inner loop that runs billions of times.

Answer (score 1):

I did the measurations with no compiler optimizations:

2) and 3) have almost the same running time, instead 1) is 10 times slower. I added also a 4)

```
for each (Enemy* e in enemies)
      e->prepare(time_elapsed);
```

valid for Visual C++ 2010 and should be sematically the same of Ferruccio's:

```
for (var iter : enemies) { iter->prepare(time_elapsed); }
```

4) is also almost as fast as 2) and 3).

With -O2 all have almost the same running time.

Comment: What's the point in making performance measurements with no optimizations on?  If you're interested in performance, why would you ever have optimizations off?

Answer (score 0):

2 and 3 are essentially identical. 1 might be faster because it performs one function call per iteration whereas 2 and 3 perform two function calls per iteration. Then again some of the function calls might get inlined. The only way to really tell is to measure.

Also, since you're throwing in lambda functions (C++0x), why not add range-based for loops to your measurements:

```
for (var iter : enemies) { iter->prepare(time_lapsed); }
```

assuming your compiler supports them, of course.

EDIT: I just noticed the vc++2010 tag. Unfortunately, your compiler does not yet support them :-(

Comment: 2 and 3 aren't identical. The bind/mem_fun stuff is much harder for the compiler to inline, as you are binding the function at runtime.

Comment: the inlining depends also on the implementation of the "prepare" method right?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it's not at all important until you've *measured* that something is currently *not fast enough*".  This question is essentially premature optimisation.  Until it's *too slow* and you've *measured* the loop as being a bottleneck, your priority is to **use the code that communicates what you're trying to do in the clearest way**.  Write nice code first, optimise later.

Comment: In my code I don't really need optimization, it's just a curiosity for future